# Windows tool to count occurences of a string in a large file?

Tags: string, count

I need a tool which counts occurences of a certain string in a large (~ 2GB) text file. Whats a good and fast tool?

Thanks!

Comment: just make a simple script for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and do `grep -o string file | wc -w`:-)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Works only on text files and only when the string occur once on each line

A simple python script:

```
input_file  = open( source_path , encoding="utf8" , mode='r' )
for line in input_file:
    if line.find("###") >= 0:
         Counter=Counter+1
```

yet `grep` shuld do the work better.